# Internet Explorer returns modified values after read SVG element content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

On Firefox and Google Chrome I can read the content of an SVG element, but with Internet Explorer some values are altered when read it.

I need **some way** to prevent Internet Explorer modify SVG values. The most convenient way would be by modifying the JavaScript code.

To read the SVG content I use the following function:

```
function xmlToString(xmlData) { 
    var xmlString;
    // IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
        xmlString = xmlData.xml;
    // Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, ...
    else // I also tried using only next line for both: IE & FF but no success
        xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlData);
    return xmlString;
}
```

Here you can test what I say by yourself: [JSFiddle experiment](https://jsfiddle.net/cm9xdwwu/) (you can try both: FF and IE).

Also, on next images I highlight where the problems are (you can check it with the previous JSFiddle).

**Mozilla Firefox and Google Chroome (Success)**

[image]

**Internet Explorer (Fail)**

[image]

Comment: You are converting from IEs internal representation and converting it back to a string (serialization).  Therefore, you are stuck with what it produces from that altered data.  If you need the origibnal contents of the SVG, you are probably going to have to read it from an external file.

Comment: The two representations are functionally identical so there seems to be no reason you cannot proceed with either serialization. Note that all UAs have non-functional serialization differences so eventually you'll find Firefox's and/or Chrome's.